# Iterate through form with many UITextFields to get values for CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitextfield

I have a form with a massive amount of UITextFields (more than 150 fields).

I was trying to figure out a way to not have to create outlets for all 150+ fields and instead iterate through UITextField elements to get the value to store into CoreData.

I want to extract any text field values and store them into a CoreData entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a **UITextField** **tag** in ascending order for example starts with 100,101...
You can set the tag value in IB inspector as shown below

[image]

Retrieve the values by iterating :-

Consider uitextfield1 tag = 100 and uitextfield2 tag = 101

```
  for(var i = 100;i<102;i++)
    {
        let myField = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as! UITextField
        print(myField.text); //save the value into your coredata
    }
```

Another way to get the textfields value:-

```
for txtField in self.view.subviews
  {
    if(txtField.isKindOfClass(UITextField.classForCoder()))
    {
        switch(txtField.tag)
        {
        case 100:
            let myField = txtField as! UITextField
            print(myField.text);//save the value into your coredata
            break;
        case 101:
            let myField = txtField as! UITextField
            print(myField.text);//save the value into your coredata
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works... would it also work to store into NSDefault?

Comment: Yes you can store it into NSUserDefault